# Manipulate an HTML element from another directory

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want select and manipulate a element HTML from another directory, is possible?

how to use the property,document.getElementById('ID') but in a file that is in another folder

Comment: JS can access only DOM that is currently exists. It can't change anything in another URL

Comment: You can use an iframe to load your other page, and if you are in the same domain, you can explore the iframe's content

Comment: I realized that it does not matter the directory, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that.

Your server serves a single HTML file, which would be rendered as DOM on your page. This DOM have no access to another files that your server is serving.

What you can do as a workaround is to load another page in an invisible `iframe`.

Let's say you have two HTML files: `hello.html` and `goodbye.html`.
Your server serves those two files as pages on `/hello` and `/goodbye` routes.

If you want to access DOM elements from `goodbye.html` being on `/hello` page you need to:

```
// hello.html
// place this iframe tag somewhere in the body of your HTML file
// use your /goodbye page path as src property of this iframe
<iframe id="goodbyeframe" src="/goodbye"></iframe>

// scripts.js
const iframe = document.getElementById('goodbyeframe');
const innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
const el = innerDoc.getElementById('myElementOnGoodbyePage')
```

But that's a hacky way indeed.

Comment: You should add that this only works if the 2 pages are on the same domain, and won't work if not loaded from a web server (i.e. it won't work from a `file:///` uri).